# Missing Approver Comments column in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, approval, content-approval

Based from my testing, **Approver Comments** column is automatically added in a SharePoint list when **Require content approval for submitted items?** is set to **Yes** in **Versioning Settings**.

Now, I have 2 SharePoint lists and have problems with **Approver Comments** column.

In my First SharePoint list, I cannot find **Approver Comments** column - it is not showing in my column list when I try to show/hide columns. Therefore, it is not just simply hidden.

In my Second SharePoint list, I had an **Approver Comments** column. I played around with it and hid it. But now, I cannot find a way to show/unhide it.

What is the logic behind the **Approver Comments** column?

I cannot simply add a column with this name as SharePoint says there is already an existing column with that name or that name is reserved.

How to bring my **Approver Comments** column back in my lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to list settings->Versioning settings-> Select "Yes" for Require content approval for submitted items.

Then Modify view->check "Approval status" column:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!

"Then Modify view->check "Approval status" column" solved it! :)